# AnimationDrawable in Android problem

Tags: android, animation

I am having a common problem doing animationdrawable in Android. I wanted to start an animation when the Activity starts, in the onCreate() method, but as many people have found, it doesn't work.

I have read lots of advice but nothing seems to work for me. If I start the animation in onClick() it works, it requires user input, not starting immediately.

I tried starting it in a separate thread in onCreate() but that doesn't work either. I read here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1818

but none of the advice worked, or I couldn't understand it.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

I've faced similar problems, and switched to overriding onWindowFocusChanged() instead of onCreate() and onResume():

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{
    if (hasFocus)
    {
        animation.start();
    }
    else
    {   
        animation.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I guess it will not give most people enough control to do what they want; for example to start an animation before a task start and stop it afterwards.

Comment: this does work, but I found that if I call `animation.start()` before `onWindowFocusChanged(true)` and subsequently again call `animation.start()` from within `onWindowFocusChanged(true)` then the animation won't start ! So what I've had to do is track the UI state. So within Vaiden's `if (hasFocus)` I set a member variable `isVisible=true;` and all subsequent `animation.start()` first check for `isVisible==true`. It's a *major* PITA when autostarting various animations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to start the animation after initialization of the view in question is complete. You should be able to do something like this:

```
final ImageView tweenImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
tweenImage.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.cubicfacetween);      
tweenImage.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =
            (AnimationDrawable) tweenImage.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();
    }
}
```

For setting src in `imageView`

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.no_network_icon)).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AnimationDrawable drawable = (AnimationDrawable) ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.no_network_icon)).getDrawable();
                drawable.start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: This worked on a Nexus 4, Nexus 5, and old Sony Erricson running 2.3 But it didn't work on a HTC One V running 4.03...Any ideas? The view which is animated simply doesn't draw...If I replace the animation with a color the view appears just fine.

Comment: problem solved by differentiating between setting the Animation.xml in background property or in src property of the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you provided you have to start the animation in a separate thread. In Java you do that by implementing the [Runnable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface and start it with

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable()); // MyRunnable inherits Runnable
t.start();
```

you can also write the code like this

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        // some code that runs outside the ui thread.
    }
}).start();
```

if you don't want to implement a whole new class. The latter is of course not that pretty but if you're making a small project it can be nice to know about.

Have you tried it this way or have you started your thread in another way?

Please also read [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) that goes over what possibilities you have to perform actions outside the ui thread and how to post methods that runs on the ui thread from your own threads.

---

*Edit:* After reviewing the link you posted you have to wait a while before starting your thread, probably until onCreate is complete. According to [the flowchart on this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) you should be able to start your animation later, for instance in the onResume call. Have you tried starting it in a method called after onCreate?

You should only *create* things in onCreate, and "start" them in onStart or onResume.